# Clicking on grammarly button triggers the modal close in react tailwind app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grammarly

when the user clicks on the Grammarly button the react app modal is triggered to close. this happens on web with the Grammarly web extension

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.